# Subscribe to geometry_msgs/Pose2D message for arduino application

Tags: ros, arduino, 2d-pose-estimate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

How to subscribe to geometry_msgs/Pose2D type message for an arduino application? Any example?

Thanks in advance.

Any help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215170/subscribe-to-geometry_msgs/pose2d-message-for-arduino-application/) by [rosdino](https://answers.ros.org/users/22812/rosdino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is a simple example that subscribes to a geometry_msgs/Pose2D topic, toggles a LED every time it receives a message and stores the data in separate variables.

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Pose2D.h>

ros::NodeHandle  nh;

void poseCb( const geometry_msgs::Pose2D& pose_msg){
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH-digitalRead(13));   // blink the led
  float x = pose_msg.x;
  float y = pose_msg.y;
  float th = pose_msg.theta;
}

ros::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Pose2D> sub("pose", &poseCb );

void setup()
{ 
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  nh.initNode();
  nh.subscribe(sub);
}

void loop()
{  
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(1);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) with karma: 962 on 2015-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosdino](https://answers.ros.org/users/22812/rosdino/) on 2015-08-06**:
Hello Gary,

Thank you for your answer.
Just one question, how do I print the x y theta values on the serial monitor? serial.print doesn't work.

**Comment by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) on 2015-08-06**:
You can't use serial.print directly since the serial port is already being used to communicate with the rosserial_python node.

You need to use the ROS' logger. There's an example under File->Examples->ros_lib->Logging in your Arduino IDE

**Comment by [rosdino](https://answers.ros.org/users/22812/rosdino/) on 2015-08-06**:
Thanks :-)